# Plotting multiple probability distributions in a single graph in R

Tags: r, probability, distribution

I tried to plot probability distributions from different sources in a single plot. I used the following codes.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggfortify)
p<- ggdistribution(dbeta, seq(0,1,0.01), shape1 = 1.777409 , shape2 = 2.7947, fill ='blue')
p<- ggdistribution(dbeta, seq(0,1,0.01), shape1 = 1.934973 , shape2 = 2.553981, fill ='red', p=p)
ggdistribution(dbeta, seq(0,1,0.01), shape1 = 0.93427 , shape2 = 1.777248, fill ='green', p=p)
```

[image: output plot]

Is it possible to use point values (min, max, median and interquartile range) instead of shape1 and shape 2 to plot the distributions?